# sending HTML5 canvas data via HTML post request

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to send the canvas data to the server side as image. I have been making an HTTP post request, but i am not able to get the data at server side. $_POST is empty but when i console the same object at JS side i get the image data.

this is the JS side

```
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
var vvFD="image=" + JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL("image/png"));
console.log(vvFD);
XHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
XHR.addEventListener('load', uploadFinish, false);
XHR.addEventListener('error', uploadError, false);
XHR.addEventListener('abort', uploadAbort, false);
XHR.open('POST', 'example_upload/upload1.php');
XHR.send(vvFD);
```

and the PHP side is...

```
  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
    //do stuff
  }
  else
    {
    echo "_POST is empty";
    }
```

I am getting the message _POST is empty.

Any one can here help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how your JS works, but I have a feeling it's sending the image in the body section of the HTTP request. $_POST won't pick that up on the server side.

Try:

```
$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
```

There is an example in the manual which will output the headers from your HTTP request.
[apache_request_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

Between these two, you should be able to capture everything coming into your php script.

Comment: thanks, i just have found the answer by searching different forums and the answer that i found is similar with that you, i was also missing the same thing that you mentioned above. Here is the link of the answer that  i found is http://www.worldofwebcraft.com/page.php?id=101&t=HTML5_use_php_and_ajax_to_save_canvas_as_png_on_your_server